# Call Property in MainViewModel from User Control ViewModel - WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am having a User Control and User Control is having its own ViewModel.

User Control has 3 textboxes and data getting populated in those three textboxes based on selection from user control ViewModel. Once the data get Populated in three textboxes, I want to call Property in ParentViewModel from user control ViewModel.

How can I do this ? 
Here is my User Control in Parent Window

```
<Controls:Info DataContext="{Binding InfoViewModel}" TabIndex="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
```

Comment: Add a dependencyproperty and bind it to a value in the parent viewmodel. When you change the value in the usercontrol, the value will be reflected (since it's bound) to the parent.

Comment: @Patrick Can you please elaborate little bit. Is there any good article or sample for this ?

Comment: You can create a relation between the 2 ViewModels. Like `this.InfoViewModel.Parent = this;`